# var access error inside findOne in forEach nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

```
 api.get('/evaluateproductratings', function(req, res){
    Product.find({}, function(err, results){
      results.forEach(function(product){
          var rate = math.divide(0.0,1);
          var count = math.add(0,0);

          product.Ingredients.split(", ").forEach(function(ingredient){
            Ingredient.findOne({title: ingredient}, function(err, ing){

              if(err) {
                console.log(err);
              }
              else if(!ing){
                rate = math.add(rate, 0.0);
                count = math.add(count, 1);
              }
              else{
                  rate = math.add(rate, ing.Weightage);
                  count = math.add(count, 1);          
              }
            })
          })   
          var finalrate = math.divide(rate,count);
          console.log(finalrate);
          product.update({$set:{'Rating': finalrate}}, function(err, result){
            if(err){
              console.log(err);
            }
            else{
              console.log('product rated successfully.');
            }
          })
        })
        res.json('all products rated successfully');
    })
})
```

the problem occurring here is that i'm not able to update the variables rate and count inside Ingredient.findOne and hence finalrate is always evaluated to NaN (i.e., 0/0) since both rate and count were initialized to 0 for every product.

ProductSchema :

```
 title:"something",
 Ingredient:"ing1, ing2, ing3"
```

IngredientSchema :

```
 title:"ing1",
 Weightage:"2"

 title:"ing2",
 Weightage:"5"

 title:"ing3",
 Weightage:"7"
```

how to solve this?

Comment: You are updating them, but... you aren't waiting for said update to occur before using them. findOne is asynchronous. `res.json()` is happening before the second trip to the database is complete.

Comment: how to resolve this? @KevinB

Comment: res.json() is for when all the products have been successfully rated.... console log is for when one product is successfully rated... currently i have 29 products in my product schema .. and 312 ingredients in my ingredientSchema

Comment: instead of downvoting the question, it would be great if people could help. :\

Comment: but... it's not that simple. the update callback is inside a forEach, so you'll need to either start using promises, or use a counter so that you know when the last callback is called and *then* use res.json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move your update function into your `Ingredient.findOne()` callback, otherwise your rate and count values won't be updated to their new values. Your update function was outside your `Ingredient.findOne()` callback which means that your `Ingredient.findOne()` and `product.update()` were executing at the same point in the flow, your update statement would've never been able to know what your rate and count were updated to in this case.

```
api.get('/evaluateproductratings', function(req, res){
    Product.find({}, function(err, results){
      results.forEach(function(product){
          var rate = math.divide(0.0,1);
          var count = math.add(0,0);

          product.Ingredients.split(", ").forEach(function(ingredient){
            Ingredient.findOne({title: ingredient}, function(err, ing){

              if(err) {
                console.log(err);
              }
              else if(!ing){
                rate = math.add(rate, 0.0);
                count = math.add(count, 1);
              }
              else{
                  rate = math.add(rate, ing.Weightage);
                  count = math.add(count, 1);          
              }

              var finalrate = math.divide(rate,count);
              console.log(finalrate);
              product.update({$set:{'Rating': finalrate}}, function(err, result){
                if(err){
                  console.log(err);
                }
                else{
                  console.log('product rated successfully.');

                  return res.json('all products rated successfully');
                }
              });
            });
          });

        });

    });
});
```